# Can I speed up parsing perforce changes/describe output?

Tags: php, regex, sed, awk, perforce

My goal is to extract changenumber/date/time/description from 'p4 changes' for a range of given changenumbers in a POST response. I made a simple PHP script that parses the necessary shell commands (hacky but it works) and populates a JSON array.

Things work fine until I start looking at 'p4 describe -s ' and parsing out a special field in there where we list the bugs associated with the changenum, like so:

bug2342 state fixed;

bug2343 state fixed;

The script has to do a separate 'p4 describe' on each changenum, which of course takes a while. I'm seeing responsetimes of 30+ seconds for ranges of ~1000 changenumbers  :(

Anything I can do to speed things up?
I am even thinking of doing things two-pass on the front end: first get all the changenums, display them (leaving bug ids blank) then asynchronously get the bug numbers in batches of ~10 or so and iteratively fill in the missing data.

```
$cmd = 'p4 changes -t -s submitted -l //depot/...@' . $changenum1 . ',' . $changenum2 . ' 2>&1 |
  awk \'BEGIN { RS = "^Change |\n^Change "; FS = "^Change |\n^Change " } {print $1 "::::"}\'';
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
$changes = split("::::", trim($output));
$cc = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($changes as $change) {
if (empty($change)) {
    continue;
}

//example here: '3193358 on 2012/10/08 11:05:42 by user@client\n "some lengthy multiline description"'
$change = trim($change);
$c = array();
$basics = preg_split( "/( |\n)/", $change);
$c["cnum"] = $basics[0];
$c["date"] = $basics[2];
$c["time"] = $basics[3];
$user = $basics[5];
$c["user"] = preg_replace('/@.*/', "", $user);
//echo "cnum: $c["cnum"], date: $c["date"]], time: $c["time"], user: $c["user"]";

//THIS IS VERY SLOW
$cmd2 = 'p4 describe -s ' . $c["cnum"] . ' 2>&1 | egrep "^bug[0-9]+" | sed -re "s/bug([0-9]+).*/\1/"';
$output2 = shell_exec($cmd2);
$bugs = split("\n", trim($output2));
$c["bugs"] = $bugs;

$pos = strpos($change, "\n"); //remove first line
if ($pos !== false) {
    $description = substr($change, $pos +1);
} else {
    $description = $change;
}
//remove multiple whitespace
$description2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $description);
//remove blank new lines etc
$description3 = preg_replace('/^\n+|^[\t\s]*\n+/m', "", $description2);

$c["desc"] = trim($description3);
$cc[$i++] = $c;
}

$output = __json_encode($cc);
```

Comment: Why do you have to run a separate 'p4 describe'? Doesn't the 'p4 changes -l' already have the entire description in the output?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The "bug<id>" part doesn't show up in the description, it's some internally added feature that I can only get with 'p4 describe'.

Comment: Why do you have to call `p4 describe` on each change number?  `p4 describe` accepts multiple change numbers as arguments.  You should be able to invoke it only once.

Comment: Perhaps the "very slow" part of your overall process is the "internally added feature" that attaches a bugID during the describe process? Can you ask your admins for more information about how that part of your Perforce system is configured? Special form-out triggers, perhaps?

Comment: @jamesdlin Oh man I can't believe I overlooked this. I switched the code around to send in all the cnums into 'p4 describe' and then parsed the results into my array. 10K entries = 2seconds and that's definitely manageable. Thanks for the tip! If you add this as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to invoke `p4 describe` separately for each change number (and thereby making multiple round-trips to the Perforce server); the `p4 describe` command accepts multiple change numbers as arguments.  You therefore should be able to invoke it only once, e.g.:

```
p4 describe -s 100 101 102 103
```